# Detecting an input into "Line In" port in the computer

Tags: c#, windows-7

I don't know if the title explained my problem, but here is what i am trying to do.

You know how there is an input jack for headphones and an input jack for microphone on a PC? Well there is also an input jack called "Line in". Here is what i need to do:

1) Detect if something is plugged into the line in jack

2) If detected, disable the jack

3) On some computers, there is a single jack in the back for microphone AND line in. Is there a way that the line in part of that jack could be disabled?

My C# program requires a person to speak into a microphone which is plugged in into the correct jack, and i can already detect that perfectly and change volume based on requirements and all that. But i have looked through the Core Audio API for Windows 7 and checked several other forums, but can't seem to find anything for detecting an input into the Line in port. Anybody here worked with detecting line in jack in C#? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `input jack microphone jack` sounds more like the correct term

Comment: @MethodMan yeah i had that originally, but saw other people referring it to as port. I'll change it for clarity!

Comment: "**core-audio**" tag explanation from StackOverflow: "CoreAudio is a low-level API for dealing with sound in _Apple's Mac OS X_ and _iOS_ operating systems". Would you please explain what does it have to do with _Windows 7_ and _C#_?

Comment: @user3078414 Sorry, i did not read the OSX IOS part, i'll remove that tag.